# How can I set the the same Culture for all my resx files?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing an WPF application. Language localization is implemented by using different resx files.

I have separate resx files for all my Views. And for each resx file I have different languages ("se", "en", and so on).

```
MyViewA.resx
MyViewA.sv.resx
MyViewA.en.resx
...
MyViewB.resx
MyViewB.sv.resx
MyViewB.en.resx
```

and so on...

For now I must set the Culture separate for each resource file.

Simplified example of what i must do now:

```
cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("se");
MyViewA.Culture = cultureInfo;
MyViewB.Culture = cultureInfo;
...
MyViewX.Culture = cultureInfo;
```

Is there an easier way to set the same Culture for all my resx files?

Comment: `MyViewA`, `MyViewB` objects - what are they?

Comment: The object are created from the resx files. So all MyViewA.resx files creates MyViewA. I don't know how this works, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easier way to set the same Culture for all my resx files?

Set the `CurrentUICulture` property of the thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE");
```

Or stick with your current approach of setting the `Culture` property of all generated `.resx` classes.